# Car speed sensor to turn on something

Tags: sensor, automotive, speed

Is there a sensor for the speed of the car that can be programmed to turn on something when a car reaches to a specified speed?

If yes, what is it’s name, and whare to find it online?

Comment: a GATSO would seem to do what you're asking. Where to find one would be off-topic...

Comment: I have a sensor that gives an audible warning if I drive too fast .... but she's not always with me, so a bit intermittent.

Answer (score 1):

With most modern cars you can attach a computer or microcontroller to the OBD-II diagnostic port and ask the engine management system how fast the car is travelling.

Or you can use one of the shaft speed measurement techniques (eg hall effect, retroreflective) on the prop shaft after the gearbox, and convert that to wheel speed.

Or you can use a GPS unit, although that won't work in tunnels.